# Improve MySQL InnoDB Full-text Search Performance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization, innodb, database-performance

1. Background:
   DB: MySQL 8.0, InnoDB engine;
   Table size: About 2M rows of 2G data;
   FULL_TEXT index column: *sentence* (TEXT data type)
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html
2. Old Query using SQL LIKE:

   `SELECT * FROM books WHERE sentence LIKE '%This is a sample search input string%' and author_id = 5 and publisher_id = 23;`
3. New Query using MySQL FULL_TEXT search:

   `SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH (sentence) AGAINST ('This is a sample search input string') and author_id = 5 and publisher_id = 23 LIMIT 1;`
4. Problems:
   I expect a lot of search speed boost from using LIKE to FULL_TEXT(match... against). But based on my testing, this isn't the case:
   For an input string with <10 words, full_text search is faster than LIKE;
   For an input string with ~25 words, the full_text search can take 3+ seconds to return which is similar to LIKE.
   And longer the string, the worse speed full_text search has which can take more than 15s.
5. Profiling the query:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html
   By looking at the profiling result, 90% of the time is spent on "FULLTEXT initialization"
6. Optimization I've tried which haven't brought speed improvement:

6.1 Rewrite query trying to use other indexes together with full-text index:

```
select * from books as b1 join books b2 on b1.author_id = b2.author_id and b1.publisher_id = b2.publisher_id WHERE b2.author_id = 5 and b2.publisher = 23 and MATCH (b1.source) AGAINST ('Sample input string') LIMIT 1;
```

6.2 Only select the document_id instead of the whole record:

```
SELECT id FROM books WHERE MATCH (sentence) AGAINST ('This is a sample search input string') and author_id = 5 and publisher_id = 23 LIMIT 1;
```

7. Questions:
   Are there any other ways that I could try to improve the search speed? According to this doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html
   I could try adding more stop words, run OPTIMIZE TABLE, move current table to a new one, or upgrading the hardware. But I'm not sure if it's worth to try those methods at all.

Answer (score 1):

- Toss the short words and any stop words
- Prefix the rest with '+' and add "IN BOOLEAN MODE"

  AGAINST ('+sample +search +input +string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

If you need the words exactly like your LIKE, then do

```
WHERE MATCH(..) AGAINST(...)
  AND ... LIKE '%This is a sample search input string%'
  AND ...
```

The FULLTEXT search will be fast, but may find documents that have the words in some other order.  The LIKE will be fast because it is only checking only a few rows (the ones that FT found).